# Loading content via AJAX destroy the font in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

1. Look at [this page](http://serviciomex24.com/directorio).
2. Press the orange `->` button and then the `<-` again.

This paginator shows the page 1 by default and load the other pages' content via AJAX. However, that default page 1 content and the ajax loaded page 1 content don't look the same in IE, even when the html and css are exactly the same!. You can see the font is thin and ugly, especially in the blue headers.

Why is this happening and how do I make it stop?

Comment: Hi Have you got a solution for this please?  I am struggling with the same.  I have noticed that the page you specified is working fine now with the pagination.  Please share it.  Thank you

Comment: @John, I posted the solution I used for this problem. I'm commenting here for you getting an email alert or something. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John, I managed to solved using this code:

```
$('.css-selector').each( function( i, el ){
    try { el.style.removeAttribute( 'filter' ); } catch( e ){}
});
```

And, if you are not using jQuery, I think this can still work:

```
try {
    document.getElemenyById('id_element').style.removeAttribute('filter');
} catch(e){}
```